# Can't monitor connection pooling in Performance Monitor

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows, ado.net

I am following [this](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/ado-net-connection-pooling/) tutorial about ADO.NET. I created a console app and I am trying this simple code to monitor the performance:

```
    // Pooling Off
    stopwatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new(connectionString + poolingOffString);
        connection.Open();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        connection.Close();
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
```

I run the app then go to performance monitor on windows as in the tutorial (pic is from the tutorial's page):
[image]

But when I try to add a counter as in the image I don't see the option `connectionpooling`, only options I see are `defaultdomain` and `sqlceip` and even if I add them as counters they do not change their values.

How can I get the `connectionpooling` option in the menu?

Comment: Try closing and reopening perfmon while you app is running. I believe perform caches counter instances.

Comment: @DanGuzman not working